# Automatically dial and call number when a button is clicked in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

My project requires me to directly make a call from an app. There's an image which should automatically dial the number on the onclick event. Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can open the dialer using this:

```
Device.OpenUri (new Uri ("tel://xxxxxxxxxx"));
```

However, the user has to actually hit a button to initiate a call.

Comment: How about sending an email when user click on email button? @Jason

Comment: I know this is not the right way. May I know what's the correct code?                                                                                 async void Call_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   Device.OpenUri (new Uri ("tel:63638111"));

  }

Comment: I have but it doesn't seem to work. Btw, how about emails? @Jason

Comment: are you trying on a device or simulator?  Have you checked for errors or exceptions?  Are you sure your event handler is being called?  I've used this technique many times and it has always worked for me.

Comment: I used a simulator. Myabe that's the cause of error.

Comment: The simulator can't make a phone call

Answer (score 1):

Just we can do it like, on Call Button clicked,

```
private void CallBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri("tel:XXXXXXXXXX"));
}
```

**Note:** Launcher is imported from *Xamarin.Essentials* and XXXXXXXXXX is the Phone Number.